# How do I iterate over a collection that is in an object passed as parameter in a jasper report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have an object A that has as an instance variable a collection of object Bs. Example:

```
public class A{
    String name;
    List<B> myList;

    ...

    public List<B> getMyList(){
       return myList;
    }

    ...
}
```

I want an instance of A to be the **only** source of information the jasper report gets. I am currently doing something like:

```
   A myObjectA = new A(...);
   InputStream reportFile = MyPage.this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.jrxml");
   HashMap<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   parameters.put("objectA", myObjectA);
   ...
   JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportFile);
   JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters,  new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(myObjectA.getMyList()));
   return JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(print);
```

thereby passing **two** *sources of information*:

1. the objectA as a concrete parameter and
2. the collection of object Bs that is in A as a bean data source

I want to pass **one** *source of information* only: objectA; and leave the data source as a JREmptyDataSource(). Is it possible to iterate over myList in the report? Even if there is an empty data source?

More generally speaking:
How do I iterate over the Bs in A by passing only A?

Thanks!

Comment: reread your question. And then rephrase it so that it is comprehensible. I didn't understand anything.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am kind of in a hurry with this. Is now more clear?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it would be more appropriate to implement your own JRDataSource - one that iterates over the Bs.